# How to achieve these type of layout [Filter Design in shopping site]?

Tags: html, css, layout, filter, e-commerce

[image: Original]

[image: My Result]

I need to achieve this type of float behaviour.

Comment: And what have you tried?

Comment: See the floating behaviour of #primary when clicking on the top left filter.

Comment: It is expected that you at least attempt to code this for yourself. Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. I would suggest that you do some additional research, either via Google or by searching SO, make an attempt and. if you still have trouble, come back with **your code** and explain what you have tried and why it did not work.

Comment: I am not able to understand why it is floating in unusual way. Any help?

Comment: What exactly is unusual about it? Isn't this how floats are supposed to work? See this https://jsfiddle.net/pkjfs74t/

Comment: Can you please have a look on this URL.https://www.evernote.com/l/AKm0LffRGU9BmLP5vfNEQ8x2nB0bqURwfv4B/image.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you desired. This works by spanning the `<aside>` element 2 item height and with including item margin. It's easier for you to see the code.
[Solution](http://codepen.io/monstrasitix/pen/OMjpbo)